# If Exists Not working as I expected

Tags: sql, postgresql

I must be overlooking something obvious with my logic in the function below. I am trying to do a before insert, where I have a master (parent) table and a child (that inherits from master).  I am trying to check if a record exists, if it does do an update, otherwise do an insert. But, my IF EXISTS is not working as I would have expected and it always results in an insert.

**Function:**

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION alerting.dataset_aggregations_insert_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM alerting.dataset_aggregations dm
          WHERE dm.dataset = NEW.dataset AND dm.start_date_epoch = NEW.start_date_epoch) THEN

       UPDATE alerting.dataset_aggregations
           SET message_count = NEW.message_count
       WHERE dm.dataset = NEW.dataset
       AND dm.start_date_epoch = NEW.start_date_epoch;

    ELSE

      INSERT INTO alerting.dataset_aggregations(dataset, start_date,start_date_epoch, message_count) VALUES(NEW.dataset, NEW.start_date, NEW.start_date_epoch,NEW.message_count);

    END IF;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Trigger:**

```
    --Before Insert Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER insert_dataset_aggregations_master
        BEFORE INSERT ON alerting.dataset_aggregations_master
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE alerting.dataset_aggregations_insert_trigger();
```

**Example Insert (Insert twice and creates two entries):**

```
INSERT INTO alerting.dataset_aggregations(dataset,start_date,start_date_epoch,message_count) VALUES('dataset1','2016-05-17T08:00:00.000Z',1463472000000,'500');
```

Comment: Well, you insert into `alerting.dataset_aggregations`, but your trigger is defined on `alerting.dataset_aggregations_master`

Comment: That is because I am using inheritance.

Comment: Afaik triggers are not inherited in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Oh duh. I see what you mean. Stupid mistake with my insert ref. I gotcha. Thanks dnoeth!